# Query the Description Value of a Picklist

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to get the value from the Description field of a picklist in CRM, this is what I am using to get the Label value, how would I change it to get the Description Value?

```
RetrieveAttributeRequest request = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
request.EntityLogicalName = "opportunity";
request.LogicalName = "country";

RetrieveAttributeResponse response = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)orgService.Execute(request);
PicklistAttributeMetadata picklist = (PicklistAttributeMetadata)response.AttributeMetadata;

foreach (OptionMetadata option in picklist.OptionSet.Options)
    {
        string picklistlabel =  option.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label.ToString();

        if (p.Column_16.ToString().ToUpper() == picklistlabel.ToString().ToUpper())
            {
                 countryid= option.Value;
            }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the description for a specific option in a optionset by accessing the `Description` property.

Like this:

`string description = option.Description.UserLocalizedLabel.Label.ToString();`

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.picklistattributemetadata_members.aspx) is a list of members exposed by the `PicklistAttributeMetadata`.