# Query the Description Value of a Picklist in Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I want to query the values from the different Picklist in Opportunity in dynamics CRM 4.0. I don't want to query the actual Opportunity, just the values from the Picklist. So if I have a Picklist called Source and it has the values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I want to query the picklist and get back those values. Is this possible? If so, how in the world do you do it?

I use Java (JAX-WS), but a .NET example is also welcome, due to the use of the same base entities.

What I've tried. I've setup the following query:

```
// Set up query ...
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
query.setEntityName("picklistmapping");
// Set up columns to retrieve ...
// Add columns to retrieve to the query ...
query.setColumnSet(new AllColumns());
```

But this query, returns an empty result!

For the record, this is a copy of the following question: [Query the Description Value of a Picklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779984/query-the-description-value-of-a-picklist). Difference: that question is about dynamics CRM 2011, mine is about **dynamics crm 4.0**! The accepted answer of that question says something with the class 'RetrieveAttributeRequest'. Except mine wsdl didn't generate that class, so I guess that's specific for dynamics crm 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Metadata Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151046.aspx) for that purpose. And [here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdeployment/thread/978e3213-5631-484e-9008-2b06542bb04e) is the similar question, where you can find code sample.

```
RetrieveAttributeRequest attributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
attributeRequest.EntityLogicalName = <your entity name>;
attributeRequest.LogicalName = <your picklist attribute name>;
attributeRequest.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;

RetrieveAttributeResponse response = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)metaService.Execute(attributeRequest);
PicklistAttributeMetadata picklist = (PicklistAttributeMetadata)response.AttributeMetadata;


foreach (Option o in picklist.Options)
{
    // do something e.g. take o.ValueValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed the solution:)! Unfortunately, this brings some collateral damage to our application, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515659/wsimport-generates-conflicting-xmltypes-for-multiple-dynamics-crm-4-0-wsdls